# (Python) - Typing out sum in answer area

Tags: python

I've been trying to code a system to solve one of those "Are you a bot" type of captchas in a game.

Pretty much what it does is gives you a mathematical question from 1-200 numbers (ex 19 + 163) and asks you to solve it at random times throughout the gameplay.

with Pyautogui I managed to find the numbers accordingly on the screen (scanning the region for the number 1-9, then adding it to the according variable (i made 5 variables from number1 to number5)

Using the example above (19 + 163) it would correspond with

19

number1 = 1, number2 = 9

163

number3 = 1, number4 = 6 and number5 = 3

and then i made a simple calculating system which is :

```
sum1 = ((number1 * 10) + number2)
sum2 = ((number3 * 100) + (number4 * 10) + number5)
sum = sum1 + sum2
print(sum)
```

But is there a way to make it so that the sum will display it in 3 seperate numbers instead of showing let's say (sum = 193) it would show (sum = 1, 9, 3) and then type it out in the answer area (I had an idea of using import keyboard for typing the answer out but i'm not sure if it works in this case)

or even better in this case if there is a way to take the sum and then make it type it out in the answer area by the code?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3zIr.jpg (Picture of the Bot captcha)

Comment: if you simple want to display the integer, can you first convert it in string that do a for loop to output?

Comment: I don't get it, are you trying to prompt the user or are you trying to programmatically circumvent your own captcha? Why are you scanning the screen with `pyautogui` for numbers that your own program has generated, and then supplying the input too?

Comment: It's not my own game. It's another game I play but there's this obnoxious "are u a human" thing that pops up every once in awhile and I want to automate it so that it does it for me (I am making a BOT that plays the game for me), now the reason I have to use the "pyautogui" in this case is because the mathematical question can't be copied and is pretty much a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```python
sum1 = ((number1 * 10) + number2)
sum2 = ((number3 * 100) + (number4 * 10) + number5)
sum_ = sum1 + sum2

lst = list(str(sum_))
sum_ = ""

for i in lst:
  sum_ = sum_ + str(i) + ", "

print(sum_[:-2])
```

This basically turns the sum into a list of digits and then combines then all while adding commas in between.

Comment: Thank you, this did solve my need. But is there a way to get the sum and type it out in notepad for an example

Comment: First of all the list conversion is redundant. Strings are also iterable. `str(i)` is also redundant, it is already a string. Lastly, you can simply use the `join` method: `print(", ".join(str(sum_)))`

Comment: keyboard.press_and_release(sum_[:-2])

This worked out just fine. Thank you! (using import keyboard)